# WebSocket - can't connect (Expected HTTP/)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using Node.JS and I am using http to use an express server which then my WebSocket is on, but when I try to connect to the socket it gives me an 'Expected HTTP/' error.

[image: Error]

My code:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send("Hello World!");
});

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server });
// web socket stuff here

server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`HTTP Server started on port ${port}`);
});
```

And then on another Node project, I have this to connect:

```js
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const ws = new WebSocket.WebSocket('ws://localhost:3000/ws');
```

Any help?

Comment: You try to connect via WebSocket to `/ws` but you dont a request handler for `/ws` only for `/` where you just output test. So what are you expecting? This is not how a WebSocket handshake works.

Comment: So, I just tried it and it worked, then I did it again and.. I get the error

Comment: Add a rounte handler for `/ws`, -> `app.get("/ws", (req, res) => { })` and use in there  `wss.handleUpgrade(...)` -> https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/HEAD/doc/ws.md#serverhandleupgraderequest-socket-head-callback

Answer (score 0):

```
//my memory in this question was that

const WebSocket = require('ws');
const socket = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 2424, host: "localhost"});

socket.on('connection', function(ws, wss) {
    
  var domain = wss.headers.origin;

//etc...
```

But maybe you have a front for communicate if is not the good response ?